# How to automount network home directories in Ubuntu 14.04 upon login

Tags: 14.04, mount, home-directory

We’d like to automount network home directories in Ubuntu 14.04. We’ve got network authentication working, but user home directories aren’t found and users land in / when logging in. If we manually change directories to /home/[username]/ then their directories automount, but we’d like the system to make /home/[username]/ the home directory automatically upon login.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to `/etc/ldap.conf` resolved the problem:

```
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory homeDirectory-home
```